# Class is not appending to the button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a button on my table. So for **Add Button** I am trying to add the button class `btn-success` to it. Then when it changes to **Remove** on the other table have the class `btn-remove`

This is my jQuery:

```
var table1 = $('#exclude-table');
    var table2 = $('#include-table');
    table1.on('click', '#AddContractBtn', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        $(this).text('Remove').addClass('btn-danger');
        table2.append(row);
    })
    table2.on('click', '#AddContractBtn', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        $(this).text('Add').addClass('btn-success');
        table1.append(row);
    })
```

**HTML**

```
`<table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable catalogueContractsTable admin-form theme-primary" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid">
        <thead id="tableHeader">
            <tr>
                <th class="bg-white">Name</th>
                <th class="bg-white">Contract Type</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">Start Date</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">End Date</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">Termination Date</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs bg-white text-center">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="exclude-table">
                <tr class=''>
                    <td>
                        Another Contract
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Neighbouring Rights Agreement
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">
                        2018/07/05
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">
2018/10/30                  </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">
                    </td>
                    <td class="updateTableRow text-center">
                        <button class="btn br2 btn-xs fs12 table-btn" id="AddContractBtn">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class=''>
                    <td>
                        Test Contract
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Publishing
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">
                        2018/07/05
                    </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">
2018/09/30                  </td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">
                    </td>
                    <td class="updateTableRow text-center">
                        <button class="btn br2 btn-xs fs12 table-btn" id="AddContractBtn">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">

                                <div class="panel">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <span class="panel-title">
                                            <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>&nbsp;Linked
                                        </span>

                                        <div class="widget-menu pull-right mr10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tableSearch" placeholder="Search Contract Name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="panel-body pn">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <legend style="display: none">Select Contracts Form</legend>

                                            <div class="panel panel-visible mbn" id="tableContainer">
                                                <div id="include-table-scroller">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable catalogueContractsTable admin-form theme-primary" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid">
        <thead id="tableHeader">
            <tr>
                <th class="bg-white">Name</th>
                <th class="bg-white">Contract Type</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">Start Date</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs bg-white">Termination Date</th>
                <th class="hidden-xs bg-white text-center">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="include-table">

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="CancelForm" value="Cancel" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="SubmitForm" value="Create" />
        </div>
    </div>
</article>`
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: You should probably remove the other class with `removeClass`, not just add the new one.

Comment: @DarthJDG how do you mean sorry? Do you mean underneath, where I have the add class, add a remove class?

Comment: You can do it on the same line, e.g. `$(this).text('Remove').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');`

Comment: Try `$(this).text('Remove').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger');` instead of `$(this).text('Remove').addClass('btn-danger');`. Similarly in other click event also do same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I have done this:

```
    var table1 = $('#exclude-table');
            var table2 = $('#include-table');
            table1.on('click', '#AddContractBtn', function () {
                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                $(this).text('Remove').addClass('btn-danger');
                table2.append(row);
            })
            table2.on('click', '#AddContractBtn', function () {
                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                $(this).text('Add').removeClass('btn-danger');
                table1.append(row);
            })
```

Comment: There have no change in your js and you post your answer why?

Comment: @CoolJK there is. I have added the `removeClass` I also added to the success class to the button on the one table.